# Google App Script and PropertiesService.getUserProperties()

Tags: google-apps-script

I use the google app script in my google spreadsheet document.

The settings of each user of my spreadsheet doc is saved in:

```
var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();.
```

To save the settings I use

```
PropertiesService.getUserProperties()setProperties({some properties}, true)
```

The problem is the first user saves his settings and another users get the settings of the first user using `PropertiesService.getUserProperties()`
But they should not, they should get own settings.

Do you have any idea how it is possible?

Answer (score 1):

They must be logging in with the same user account for this to happen; a user can only ever access their own user properties. This could be because any triggers were created on your own account (say for form submissions), or web apps were deployed to run as you.

Share a copy of your sheet (andrew@roberts.net) if you would like me to a take a deeper look.

Answer (score 1):

In fact as the support answered me, it is not a bug. I had wrong user properties on handling triggering event.

User properties are private to the user executing the script. However, when you setup an installable onEdit trigger, the code always runs as the user that setup the trigger:

"... runs with the authorization of the user who created the trigger, even if another user with edit access opens the spreadsheet."
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable
Since the code always runs as the same user, it's always accessing the same user properties. In general it's not possible to get the identity of a user if they haven't authorized the script.